# Add condition to for loop dataframe dictionary import

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, conditional-statements, glob

I currently have a dictionary consisting of 11 imported dataframes of various sizes. I want to add a condition so that i only import the dataframes that hold a certain number of observations, say 50k.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

monthly_files = glob.glob("Module 6/data/Month_xx_data/*")
file_name = os.path.basename(monthly_files[0])

monthly_data = {}

for file_path in monthly_files:
month = os.path.basename(file_path)[:-4]
monthly_data[month]=pd.read_csv(file_path)

monthly_data
```

partial results from dictionary:

'{'Month-01':        Account_ID Transaction_Timestamp  Factor_A  Factor_B Factor_C  
0               5  2009-01-08T00:16:41Z         2         6       VI
1              16  2009-01-20T22:40:08Z         2         6       VI
2              28  2009-01-19T13:24:55Z         2         6       VI
3              40  2009-01-05T16:10:58Z         2         6       VI
4              62  2009-01-21T19:13:13Z         2         6       VI
...           ...                   ...       ...       ...      ...
54530      144190  2009-01-13T11:53:44Z         2         6       VI
54531      144191  2009-01-01T12:54:50Z         7         6       MC
54532      144200  2009-01-02T19:28:47Z         7         6       MC
54533      164389  2009-01-31T08:57:10Z         7         6       MC
54534      164408  2009-01-31T21:15:56Z         2         6       VI

```
    Factor_D Factor_E  Response Transaction_Status Month
```

0            20        A      1020           Approved   Jan
1            20        H      1020           Approved   Jan
2            21      NaN      1020           Approved   Jan
3            20        H      1020           Approved   Jan
4            20        B      1020           Approved   Jan
...         ...      ...       ...                ...   ...
54530        20        H      1020           Approved   Jan
54531        20      NaN      1020           Approved   Jan
54532        20      MCC      1020           Approved   Jan
54533        30      MCC      1020           Approved   Jan
54534        20        H      1020           Approved   Jan

[54535 rows x 10 columns],

'Month-02':        Account_ID Transaction_Timestamp  Factor_A  Factor_B Factor_C  
0               3  2009-02-21T23:23:47Z         2         6       VI
1               7  2009-02-14T11:35:42Z         2         6       VI
2              17  2009-02-04T10:55:54Z         2         6       VI
3              21  2009-02-26T09:33:05Z         2         6       VI
4              24  2009-02-12T10:35:55Z         2         6       VI
...           ...                   ...       ...       ...      ...
44375      180333  2009-02-20T08:11:51Z         8        18       AX
44376      180334  2009-02-20T08:31:06Z         8        18       AX
44377      180335  2009-02-20T08:31:27Z        10         6       DI
44378      180336  2009-02-20T08:33:28Z         2         6       VI
44379      180338  2009-02-20T08:19:56Z         7         6       MC

```
    Factor_D Factor_E  Response Transaction_Status Month
```

0            20        B      1020           Approved   Feb
1            20        C      1020           Approved   Feb
2            20        H      1020           Approved   Feb
3            20        C      1020           Approved   Feb
4            20        G      1020           Approved   Feb
...         ...      ...       ...                ...   ...
44375        20      NaN      1020           Approved   Feb
44376        20      NaN      1020           Approved   Feb
44377        20      NaN      1020           Approved   Feb
44378        35        H      1020           Approved   Feb
44379        20      MCP      1020           Approved   Feb

[44380 rows x 10 columns]'

I tried adding in an if statements but can't get anything to even run. What I would expect is only the data frames with x number of observations to be brought in. Using the two examples above, results in month 2 would be excluded as it falls below 50k observations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem with the if statement is, but on a first glance have you tried the following approach?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

monthly_files = glob.glob("Module 6/data/Month_xx_data/*")
file_name = os.path.basename(monthly_files[0])

monthly_data = {}

for file_path in monthly_files:
    month = os.path.basename(file_path)[:-4]
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    if len(df)> 50000:
        monthly_data[month]=df

monthly_data
```